# How to run a class before the initiation of SLF4J - Logback?

Tags: java, spring, slf4j, logback

As the title says, I want to run a class that will check if a property exists in a directory before the initiation of logback. So what I've tried is I put a listener that will fire at startup before the listener of spring and I've made sure that no Logger is used in this listener. But the Logger still manage to fire before my listeners. Here's my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false"
         version="3.0" 
         id="WebApp_ID" >

    <display-name>SekaiServer</display-name>

<!-- My listeners -->
   <listener>
    <listener-class>listener.InitLog</listener-class>
  </listener>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>listener.InitConfig</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>listener.InitListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

   <!--
        - Location of the XML file that defines the root application context.
        - Applied by ContextLoaderListener.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        classpath:spring/application-config.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-context.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!--
        - Servlet that dispatches request to registered handlers (Controller implementations).
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: You should tell us what you want to achieve, not how. Perhaps there is a different approach to your problem.

Comment: So my problem: Logback uses a properties file under /opt which I push there when the server start for the first time (that's the mission of `InitLog`). And so, when  logback start to load logback.xml before my InitListener, it will not found the file.